# Problems with the divide function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with the NumPy.divide() function.

For example, I want to use this function np.divide(y, x),
x and y are both NumPy arrays with the size of (147,1), but when I ask for the shape of both, x has the shape (147,1) and y (147,).
The result of the function should be a new array with the same size (147,1), but right now, I get an array with the size (147,147).

I already figured out that y is missing the column value, and this causes my problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

I tried:
y.reshape(y.shape[0],-1)
but it didn't solve the problem.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why -1?  Why not the obvious `y.reshape((y.shape[0],1))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
np.divide( x, y.reshape((y.shape[0],1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do element-wise division, you need to remove the second dimension, i.e. `1`.

Here's a little example.

```py
>>> x = np.random.random(147)
>>> y = np.random.random(147)
>>> wrong_y = np.random.random((147,1))
>>> (x / y).shape
(147,)
>>> (x / wrong_y).shape
(147, 147)
```

By the way, `numpy.divide()` and `/` (on two ndarray) are the same function.